# Magento 2 Editing javascript

Tags: magento2, javascript

All I'm trying to do is add a method to an existing js file. Specifically `place-order.js`, I understand that I need to do something to requirejs and I understand the logic behind it but for the life of me I can't edit it or understand how to change the js file in place with an edited one.

Can anyone save me?

Comment: How about this issue?

Comment: Sorry, I have not had the chance to check it out. For some reason the logger php file in Checkout has erased itself (no more long nights for me) need to solve this issue before i can continue.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you want to override `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/place-order.js`. **Basically, you can override the Javascript via Require Js - `requirejs-config.js` in our module. The requirejs config for all configs will be generated under `pub/static/_requirejs`.** So, may we need to delete the requirejs config in this folder. And then, refresh our page, Magento will generate the new one with our custom js.

An simple example:

--Create a custom module `Vendor/Module`.
--Override `place-order.js`:

*app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js*

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/place-order':
            'Vendor_Module/js/model/place-order'
        }
    }
};
```

--Create our custom js: `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/model/place-order.js`.

### Why we use some "shortcuts" in our requirejs config?

This is because, the js and html template will be load from `pub/static`.

Comment: Can I replace the js file with a new one in the same module? Is it required to create a new module just for one file?

Comment: I'm confused about your question: `Can I replace the js file with a new one in the same module?`.